# remove element from html list using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my jquery source

[image]

And this is my html source.

[image]

The add element in list works but remove doesn't work.

However, when I remove the parameter from .remove()   it removes the element, but I will have more than one ul list in a page.  I need to specify ul list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector to remove is backwards. It should be

`$('ul#family_list li:last').remove()`

Also, in future, please post your code in code tags, rather than posting an image of it

Comment: Sorry, I am quite new to stackoverflow.   How do you write codes ?

Comment: @mistysnake, Just leave 4 space at the begining of line then write your code. for inline code write between ``

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is incorrect. Use

```
 $('ul#family_list li:last').remove();
```

***or***

```
 $('ul#family_list').remove('li:last')
```

You should also read [**docs**](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) properly

Answer (score 0):

try this: `$('ul#family_list li:last').remove()`